# Geometry Nodes: Extrude in World Space on Rotated Mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector, transform-orientation

I'm trying to extrude vertices upwards in world space, but I'm not sure how to correct for a rotated mesh. Would love a little help in figuring out how to transform that vector!

[image: node tree]
[image: sphere and rotated sphere]

EDIT: Here's the solution:
[image: final nodes to rotate vector]

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: @StefLAncien why would someone need a file for such a simple question?

Comment: so the simple answer is don't rotate the object. the not as simple answer is use and 'object info' node with the 'self object' node as the *object*, use the rotation to rotate the vector you are using (make sure to invert the rotate - the 'vector rotate' node has a checkbox for this).

Comment: that did the trick, thanks!